# IPv6 radvd advise static IP as gateway?

Tags: ipv6, radvd

I am running `radvd` (2.17-2, Debian Buster) on a local network to provide IPv6 access. I would like to make `radvd` advertise the static IP of the interface (e.g. `2001::1/64`) as the gateway IP instead of the link-local address (like `fe80::something/64`). I have tried `AdvRASrcAddress` but it seems to be only effective for LL addresses so I can't specify `2001::1/64` there.

How to make `radvd` advertise the static IP as gateway instead of the LL address?

If `radvd` isn't up to this task, I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) kind of question, what is the actual goal here?   I don't believe what is asked for is possible in the protocol (nothing specific to radvd), but it's also unclear what the purpose is.

Comment: Is the actual goal to just to not have an auto-assigned address rather than specifically wanting a global unicast address? If so, you could assign a custom link-local address?